# SQL MIN of multiple columns handle null values

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate-functions, coalesce, isnull

I'm trying to use `MIN()` aggregate function and fetch the minimum date from two columns and I was able to write the SQL query for this. But If one of the columns is having NULL values my query below is taking default date as '1900-01-01T00:00:00Z'. It should take the date from either Column1 or Column2 whichever has a value.

Here is the schema and the data [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/87bc1/1)

```
+----+--------------+---------------+
| ID | ObservedDate | SubmittedDate |
+----+--------------+---------------+
|  1 | '2017-02-14' | '2017-02-15'  |
|  1 | '2017-01-21' | '2017-01-22'  |
|  2 | '2017-01-21' |               |
+----+--------------+---------------+
```

**Query**

```
SELECT [ID],
        CASE WHEN MIN(ObservedDate)<=MIN(SubmittedDate) 
             THEN COALESCE(MIN(ObservedDate),MIN(SubmittedDate))
        ELSE COALESCE(MIN(SubmittedDate),MIN(ObservedDate)) end as RiskReferenceDate
FROM Measurements
group by ID
```

The reason I used `COALESCE` is because I want my query to consider the data from the column which has the value and ignore the column which has null value

**Expected Result**

```
+----+-------------------+
| ID | RiskReferenceDate |
+----+-------------------+
|  1 | '2017-01-21'      |
|  2 | '2017-01-21'      |
+----+-------------------+
```

Comment: In your Sql Fiddle instead of '' you put NULL (2, '2017-01-21 00:00:00', null)

Comment: Your desired output conflicts with what you are saying. You say you want MIN but your desired output is MAX. And '' <> NULL. When you have an empty string as a date it is implicitly converted to 1900-01-01.

Comment: I'm sorry I updated the desired result

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not `NULL` values.  Your problem is empty strings. This is inserted as date 0.

The simplest solution is to fix your code to insert the correct value, as shown in this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/61e26/5).

You can enforce this by adding a check constraint:

```
alter table Measurements add constraint chk_measurements_ObservedDate check (ObservedDate > '2000-01-01');  -- or whatever date

alter table Measurements add constraint chk_measurements_SubmittedDate check (SubmittedDate > '2000-01-01');  -- or whatever date
```

If you have existing data in the table, you can do:

```
update Measurements
    set ObservedDate = NULLIF(ObservedDate, 0),
        SubmittedDate = NULLIF(SubmittedDate, 0)
    where ObservedDate = 0 or SubmittedDate = 0;
```

You can fix this in place with a bit more complexity in the query:

```
SELECT [ID],
       (CASE WHEN MIN(NULLIF(ObservedDate, 0)) <= MIN(NULLIF(SubmittedDate, 0)) 
             THEN COALESCE(MIN(NULLIF(ObservedDate, 0)), MIN(NULLIF(SubmittedDate, 0)))
             ELSE COALESCE(MIN(NULLIF(SubmittedDate, 0)), MIN(NULLIF(ObservedDate, 0)))
        END) as RiskReferenceDate
FROM Measurements
GROUP BY ID;
```

But I strongly urge you to fix the data.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is being caused by the empty string you have inserted into one of your date columns, you should fix that really.

Anyway, this seems to work:

```
with a as (
  select   ObservedDate Dt
  from     Measurements
  where ObservedDate <> ''
  union all
  select   SubmittedDate
  from     Measurements
  where SubmittedDate <> ''
)
select min(Dt)
from a
```